# Re-writing an npm package on github

Tags: javascript, git, typescript, github, npm

I have a [project](https://github.com/cmseaton42/node-ethernet-ip) that is used by a relatively decent number of people and has several contributors.  I would like to rewrite the entire library in typescript but I'm not sure what the best way to go about it is.  How do I preserve the history of the project while rewriting the entire project? My gut feel is to simply start with a fresh repo locally and then eventually push it as a new major revision but I'm not sure how that will effect the current for history? Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have everything in history same,

1. create a new **branch** and replace all code with new typescript
2. create a pull request.
3. For conflicts you have to take local & ignore from server since you know your files are latest ones.
4. merge pull request.
5. verify all works.

By this approach it will have old history & contributors intact for tracking.

Although there are always some complications in something new from scratch like:

- bugs/issues reported for old code are resolved or pending or even relevant now.
- old un-merged pull request will either needs to merged if relevant otherwise it will become obsolete with new typescript code. I can see many open pull requests already.
- new file names will have to history to track since added/replaced old but project will have intact history with contributions for reference.

Having new repository & replacing old will not track old contributions & there will be no way of tracking. You can also make new repository/project & leave old one intact but it is entirely up-to you and different decision.